# Is there a way to override the behavior of WebView?

Tags: android, android-webview

I get the `WebView` from my layout:

```
        WebView webView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
```

I want to override the behavior of `onKeyDown`.
Normally, I can override it by subclassing.

```
        WebView webView = new WebView(this) {

        @Override
        public boolean onKeyDown (int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // Do my stuff....
        }
}
```

However, since I got the WebView by using `findViewById`, is there a way to override the method?

P.S: It is actually a much more complicated case, and I can't Override `onKeyDown` in `MainActivity`, because it call the `onKeyDown` in `WebView` first.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to override certain methods, you have to create a custom `WebView` class which `extends WebView`.

It would look something like this:

```
public class CustomWebView extends WebView {

    public CustomWebView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CustomWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CustomWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        /* any initialisation work here */
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        /* your code here */
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

}
```

For this to work, you have to change your XML layout file accordingly:

```
<com.example.stackoverflow.CustomWebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Also, when you are inflating the `WebView`, make sure you are casting it to the correct type which is `CustomWebView`.

```
CustomWebView webView = (CustomWebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

Otherwise, you will get a `java.lang.ClassCastException`.